# $\mathbb{R}, d(x,y)=|e^x-e^y|$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$ \mathbb{R}, d(x,y)=|e^x-e^y|$
Given is this metric on R.
I know that it’s incomplete and understand why, but I wonder how I could complete this metric space? Since it’s not so much that values are missing but rather that divergent sequences are made Cauchy by this metric, I don’t know how I’d do this.

Comment: No, because I know that the metric space is incomplete. But you can always complete a metric space and I’m wondering what the completion of this one would look like.

Comment: It might help to look at an isometric space endowed with the Euclidean metric - see the accepted answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314444/is-mathbbr-complete-when-endowed-with-the-metric-d-x-y-ex-ey

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the image: $\exp(\Bbb{R}) = (0, +\infty)$, and this second interval is an incomplete metric space which can be completed by including the endpoint $0$ to get the closed interval $[0, +\infty)$. The preimage of $0$ under $\exp$ would typically be labeled "$- \infty$", so the closure/completion of the metric space $\left( \Bbb{R}, \exp \right)$ would be $[-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Naming the metric $ \text{exp} $ seems slightly confusing to me. I would stick with $ d $.

Comment: This is very clear, thank you.

Comment: Closure and completion are not the same. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543578/is-every-closure-of-a-metric-space-a-completion

Comment: @Thomas In general they're not, but here the map $\exp: \Bbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ is bijective, continuous, and even an isometry (when the second space $(0, \infty)$ is endowed with the usual metric), which means that the closure of the image will be homeomorphic to the completion of the metric space under the $\exp$ metric.